# Getting error "Call to a member function setTitle()" after install extension

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

I have installed an extension on the website. After that I am getting error on the website:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setTitle() on
>   boolean in
>   /var/www/example/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Form/Register.php:43
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/example/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297):
>   Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register->_prepareLayout() #1
>   /var/www/example/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout)) #2
>   /var/www/example/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('customer/form_r...',
>   'customer_form_r...') #3
>   /var/www/example/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('customer/form_r...',
>   'customer_form_r...') #4
>   /var/www/example/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element),
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) #5
>   /var/www/example/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Mo in
>   /var/www/example/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Form/Register.php
>   on line 43

How to fix the issue?

Comment: After installation did you clear cache?because when you install new extension and don't clear cache then it throw these kind of error so first clear cache then check.

Comment: I have done it.

Comment: this error is due to missing `head` block in your module. check out this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109928/how-can-solve-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-settitle-on-a-non-object-i)

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat, Can you please let me know where I need to check this in my module?

Comment: you can find this using grep command in ubuntu `grep ir "setTitle(" app/code/`

Comment: But when I have installed this extension on development server then there is no error. So I think this is not extension issue.

Comment: ok..but have you tried to run that command once and also run di:compile command `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`. might be something can be up on live server.

Comment: will this command work on magento 1?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set Title in your controller action like below.

```
public function IndexAction() {
  $this->loadLayout(); // do this first
  $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Title')); // You need to add this line.
  $this->renderLayout(); // render as usual
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but it is not working